# WCF woes: request and response classes

Tags: c#, wcf

Could someone *please* explain to me how the request and response model works in WCF? I have a simple service that exposes a method called getRateOfExchange with a single integer parameter that returns rateOfExchange[], but the Reference.cs file that is generated from the service contains lots of classes:

getRateOfExchange (seems to be the parameters)

getRateOfExchangeRequest

getRateOfExchangeResponse

I have tried every permutation of these classes and their methods but nothing works. Intuitively you would expect to create a request object with the parameter object as a parameter, and then pass this request to the method on the response that executes the request to the sever.

But no.

It has to be painful.

Can someone please explain?

**UPDATE**

Thank you Gigi, but my classes don't look like that.

If I follow your model, my request would look like this:

```
CharterServices.charterServiceClient proxy = new CharterServices.charterServiceClient();

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel));
{
    using (proxy as IDisposable)
    {
        var response = proxy.getRateOfExchange()
    }
}
```

However, my getRateOfExchange() method requires a getRateOfExchange object, so the above code doesn't compile.The getRateOfExchange class contains parameters that are the parameters to the proxy.getRateOfExchange() method. I have tried creating an instance of this class and passing it the above method, like this:

```
using (proxy as IDisposable)
{
    var rateOfExchange = new Service.getRateOfExchange()
    {
        charterEnquiryId = 1550003668
    };

    using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel));
    {
        using (proxy as IDisposable)
        {
            var response = proxy.getRateOfExchange(rateOfExchange);

            foreach (var rateOfExcchange in response)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(rateOfExcchange.fromCurrencyName);
            }
        }
    }                    
}
```

but it hangs when trying to call getRateOfExchange().

Aaargh! I know the service is working because I can execute a request in SoapUI to the same WSDL.

Can you help?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it hangs", but if you pass an object as a parameter, then it needs to have a DataContract. There is an example in the code when you create a new WCF application, or see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually not painful at all. Once you generate the proxy/client classes, you just create an instance of the client and then call the methods as if they were local method calls.

I can't explain the whole process here, but I'll instead refer you to the [intro](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/11/c-wcf-minimal-client-and-server-using.html) I wrote over a year ago which explains the whole process in terms of a simple example.

You can test the service using the WCF Test Client even before you've written your own client. Writing the client is very easy if you use the Service References.

Here's an excerpt from the code from that blog post illustrating how to use client code, modified to have a `using` block and use the `var` keyword for brevity:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var service = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
        {
            var response = service.GetData(5);
            Console.WriteLine(response);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's considered bad practice to use `using` with WCF proxies: [Avoiding Problems with the Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I used similar code to get exchange rates from my service, but as I say it hangs when calling the service. What I mean by hanging is going into the service code to run and never returning. What on earth can I be doing wrong??

Comment: Thanks for the link Tim, that's very interesting. I shall go through my code and apply this pattern!

Answer (score 0):

The system was throwing an exception which was not being caught, so the component model decided to hang! Fixed it now.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose `rateOfExchange` is a `List` of `integers`, I have just added 10 numbers to it, from 1 to 10.

Then this list is sent as a parameter to the `getRateOfExchange` method of the service client object.

```
List<int> rateOfExchange=new List<int>();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
rateOfExchange.Add(i);
}

//Service Call
ServiceClient obj=new ServiceClient();
var response=obj.getRateOfExchange(rateOfExchange);
foreach(var item in response)
{
Console.WriteLine(item);
} 
Console.ReadLine();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I used similar code to get exchange rates from my service, but as I say it hangs when calling the service. What I mean by hanging is going into the service code to run and never returning. What on earth can I be doing wrong??

Comment: Try regenerating the proxy again. Maybe your parameter rateOfExchange is too big or lengthy. Or there is some error in the service. Have you tested the service alone using WCF test client?